# Kibana visualization not showing analyzed fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I am working on a based facebook comments dashboard from facebook graph api using elasticsearch5 & kibana5. I add some analyzed fields and they are appearing in the discover part on Kibana but when going to the visualization i don't find those fields.

My facebook comments index :

```
PUT fb_comments
{
  "settings": {
      "analysis": {},
      "mapping.ignore_malformed": true
  },
  "mappings": {
      "fb_comment": {
          "dynamic_templates": [
              {
                  "created_time": {
                      "match": "created_time",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type": "date",
                          "format": "epoch_second"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  "message": {
                      "match": "message",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "simple"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  "strings": {
                      "match_mapping_type": "string",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

[The field message the analyzed one is appearing in discover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCZJN.png)
[The field message the analyzed one is not appearing in visualization part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPHeI.png)

Comment: Hi, I not sure, but in elastic 5 type "string" change to "keyword" if not analyzes and to "text" if analyzed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html
Try change mapping to:
{
                  "strings": {
                      "match_mapping_type": "string",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type": "keyword"                          
                      }
                  }
              }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
So in **elasticsearch 4.X** we had **string type** and then you specified the **type of analyzer** if you wish to be analyzed. In **elasticsearch 5.X** we have two types **keyword** which is automatically **aggregated and not analyzed**, and the 2nd is **text** which is autmatically **analyzed and not aggregated**. The solution is if you want an **analyzed field and aggregated at the same time** you should add a property **"fielddata":true** and it will be analyzed and aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to a memory limitation. As per Kibana 5 help, analyzed fields might required more memory.

I checked my memory and it is indeed used at its max capacity.

Comment: Actually i didn't so i stopped using analyzed fields didn't figure out any solutions, and you are right i am already facing problems with memory, elasticsearch isn't stable.

Comment: I will let you know if I find anything. I would prefer not have to stop using analyzed fields..